# iOS: dispatch_get_global_queue QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND crashes on 7.1.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, contacts

I have following snippets of code that fetches contacts by using block:

```
if (&ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions != NULL) {
            CFErrorRef error = nil;

            addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, &error);

            ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {

                dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        if (error) {
                            //...
                        } else if (!granted) {
                            //...
                        } else {
                            // access granted
                          //...
                        }
                    });
                });
```

It works fine on both `7.1.2` and `8.1.3` versions.

However when I try to change `dispatch_get_main_queue` to `dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0)` it works on `8.1.3` but **crashes** on `7.1.2`

```
if (&ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions != NULL) {
                CFErrorRef error = nil;

                addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, &error);

                ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
                        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{ // BAD ACCESS
                    if (error) {
                                //...
                            } else if (!granted) {
                                //...
                            } else {
                                // access granted
                              //...
                            }
                        });
                    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `QOS_CLASS_` identifiers were introduced in iOS 8.  You need to use the `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_` identifiers if you want to support iOS 7.

Comment: so what can I write instead `dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0),` ? what is analog of `QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND `?

Comment: `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND` would be the equivalent.

Comment: Any differences we should be aware of?